# Java bouncing ball. Why does the speed of the ball doubled, every time when a new thread is made?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to make a Java bouncing ball program which can add multiple balls by clicking the "start button". Each ball is in its own thread, that's means 10 ball instances = 10 threads!
But when i try to do so, every time a new thread is made, the speed of the ball doubles.

My question:
1. How comes that the speed is doubled? 
2. And how to let each ball operates in an apart thread(10 balls, 10 threads)

```
    package test3;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test2 extends JFrame{
    int width = 1000;
    int height = 500;
    BallPanel ballPanel = new BallPanel();

    public Test2() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 10));
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ballPanel.start();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(start);

        add(buttonPanel);
        add(ballPanel);
        ini();
    }

    private void ini(){
        setTitle("Test");
        setSize(width, height);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class BallPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
        int panelWidth = 900;
        int panelHeight = 370;
        ArrayList<Ball> ball = new ArrayList<Ball>();

         public BallPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panelWidth, panelHeight));
        }

        public void start(){
            if (ball.size() < 10) {
                ball.add(new Ball());
            }

            new Thread(this).start();
        }

        public synchronized ArrayList<Ball> movement(ArrayList<Ball> ball){
            for (int i = 0; i < ball.size(); i++) {
                if (ball.get(i).getCurrentX() < 0 || ball.get(i).getCurrentX() > panelWidth - 10) {
                    ball.get(i).setIncrementX(ball.get(i).getIncrementX() * -1);
                } else if (ball.get(i).getCurrentY() < 0 || ball.get(i).getCurrentY() > panelHeight - 10) {
                    ball.get(i).setIncrementY(ball.get(i).getIncrementY() * -1);
                }

                ball.get(i).setCurrentX(ball.get(i).getCurrentX() + ball.get(i).getIncrementX());
                ball.get(i).setCurrentY(ball.get(i).getCurrentY() + ball.get(i).getIncrementY());
            }
            return ball;
        }


        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (ball != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ball.size(); i++) {
                    g.setColor(ball.get(i).color);
                    g.fillOval(ball.get(i).getCurrentX(), ball.get(i).getCurrentY(), ball.get(i).getRadius(), ball.get(i).getRadius());
                } 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                movement(ball);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                repaint();

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test2();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The ball class

```
package test3;

import java.awt.Color;

public class Ball {
    int currentX;
    int currentY;
    int incrementX;
    int incrementY;
    int radius;
    Color color;



    public Ball() {
        this.currentX = 7;
        this.currentY = 0;
        this.incrementX = 1;
        this.incrementY = 1;
        this.radius = 10;
        this.color = Color.red;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public int getIncrementX() {
        return incrementX;
    }

    public void setIncrementX(int incrementX) {
        this.incrementX = incrementX;
    }

    public int getIncrementY() {
        return incrementY;
    }

    public void setIncrementY(int incrementY) {
        this.incrementY = incrementY;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int getCurrentX() {
        return currentX;
    }

    public void setCurrentX(int currentX) {
        this.currentX = currentX;
    }

    public int getCurrentY() {
        return currentY;
    }

    public void setCurrentY(int currentY) {
        this.currentY = currentY;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color){
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works, but I only see one thread, how was your code when you had a thread per ball?

Comment: Your title should be a question like "Why does the ball speed double with each thread I add?" and you should stick to solving that single problem for this question.  It's also good form to close your question body by restating your question.  That avoids answerers having to scroll a lot.  Good outline is: title as question, what you were trying to do, what you tried, what you expected, what happened, question restatement.

Comment: @Titus, for that matter, the program probably should have a single thread that animates all of the balls.  Using a thread per animated object almost never is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

stop() is setting app = null and interrupting the thread, but the InterruptedException is being swallowed in the run() method so the thread keeps running.  Then when start() is run again, another Thread is created, which results in the movement() method being called by both threads, doubling the movement speed.

Comment: your answer has nothing to do with my question. The stop method isn't important in this post.

Comment: I also don't see anything related to a `stop` method in the question. But the "core" of the answer is correct: For each added ball, a new thread is created. And each thread will move *all* balls. So the general design is a bit flawed...

Comment: @Marco13 You're half right. What I need is for each added ball, a new thread for that ball is created.  And each thread will move a "SINGLE" ball.

Comment: As jameslarge pointed out in the comments above: Using one thread for each ball probably does not make sense (unless it's some academic toy). This may still "work" for 5 balls or maybe even for 20 balls, but it's a **huge** waste of resources. If you moved the line `new Thread(this).start();` into the *constructor* of the ball pane, it could already work properly (maybe change the `ArrayList` of balls to a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` to avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException`)